# Error 302 with backpack middleware in my tenants

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I have a system that has tenants with different domain. I am using stancl/tenancy for the tenancy package.

I am trying to access the `/user` of backpack in my tenant and I have 302 errors on the process because backpack considers users in the tenant as guest even after login.

My route goes like this:

```
Route::group([
'namespace'  => '\App\Http\Controllers',
'prefix'     => config('backpack.base.route_prefix', 'admin'),
'middleware' => ['web', 'universal', backpack_middleware(),
    InitializeTenancyByDomain::class, ],
], function () {
    Route::crud('user', 'UserCrudController');

});
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It seems to me that the problem is in your midleware